# I want to hide a div by resizing the window

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I tried to hide a div with jQuery with the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ( window.innerHeight < 750 ) {
    $("footer").animate({'height' : '0px'}, 500);
  }
  if ( window.innerHeight > 750 ) {
    $("footer").animate({'height' : '35px'}, 500);
  } 
});
```

I have tested it in Chrome and it only works once. It only disappears and never appears again by resizing.

Is there a mistake in my code or is it the wrong solution?

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: Are you wanting a JS solution only or are open to media queries?

Comment: The resize event fires continously, so animation isn't really doable like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is to use a media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

For example, if you have an id of #divOne, you style the div as normal and add a separate media query as `display: none;` for when the window shrinks to a specified width. In this case, the div hides when the width of the window is below 600px:

```
#divOne {display: block; height: 200px; background: #000; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #divOne {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to mark as correct answer. I need the rep!

Answer (score 0):

That means this condition `if ( window.innerHeight > 750 ) {` is never executing because browser `window.innerHeight` is less than 750. To see the value in console log it like this:

```
console.log(window.innerHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is jQuery Implementation:

Suppose you want to hide `div1` when the window width is less than `750px` and display it again if the window width is greater than `750px`

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1{
    width:100%;
    padding:30px;
    background:#1d1d1d;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(setDivVisibility);
function setDivVisibility(){
     if (($(window).width()) < '750'){  
     $('#div1').css('display','none');  
     } else {  
     $('#div1').css('display','block');  
     } 
 }
```

**Working jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a8V9V/